# Log4j 1.2 custom loglevel with levelmatchfilter in properties file

Tags: log4j

I tried to implement a levelmatchfilter for a custom loglevel and configure it within a properties file.
Used the template for the chrunchify loglevel for creating mine:
    http://crunchify.com/java-how-to-create-your-own-logging-level-in-log4j-configuring-log4j/

Configured my properties file as follwing:

```
log4j.rootLogger.level=DEBUG

# LOG4J daily rolling log files configuration
log4j.rootLogger=debug, DebugAppender, InfoAppender, ErrorAppender, ChangeAppender

#DebugAppender (Debug)
log4j.appender.DebugAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.File=./log/debug/ngpmt_debug.log
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
log4j.appender.DebugAppender.Threshold=DEBUG

#InfoAppender (Loud)
log4j.appender.InfoAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.InfoAppender.File=./log/loud/ngpmt_info.log
log4j.appender.InfoAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.InfoAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.InfoAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
log4j.appender.InfoAppender.Threshold=INFO

#ErrorAppender (Silent)
log4j.appender.ErrorAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ErrorAppender.File=./log/silent/ngpmt_error.log
log4j.appender.ErrorAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.ErrorAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ErrorAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
log4j.appender.ErrorAppender.Threshold=WARN

#ChangeAppender (Changes)
log4j.appender.ChangeAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ChangeAppender.File=./log/silent/ngpmt_changes.log
log4j.appender.ChangeAppender.File.filter.a=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter     
log4j.appender.ChangeAppender.File.filter.a.LevelToMatch=CHANGE#at.xtention.pqm.ngpmt.gui.helpers.Change 
log4j.appender.ChangeAppender.File.filter.a.AcceptOnMatch=true    
log4j.appender.ChangeAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.ChangeAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ChangeAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
```

I have 3 log-files with different scopes. Additional to that i want a log-file where only CHANGE-Level messages are logged to.